# How does Google Dart handle namespaces / packages when converting to javascript?

Tags: dart

I have lets say two game projects: zoo 1 and zoo 2. Both have a class named animal. In order to avoid conflicts between the two classes with the same name I wrap them in functions. How does Dart handle such a scenario? Through packages or libraries? A master class used as a namespace? If so then how does it convert those to javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dart doesn't have namespaces. You can use import prefixes for that

```
import 'package:zoo1/zoo1.dart' as zoo1;
import 'package:zoo2/zoo2.dart' as zoo2;

main() {
  print(new zoo1.Animal());
  print(new zoo2.Animal());
}
```

you can also use the prefix only for one of these

```
import 'package:zoo1/zoo1.dart';
import 'package:zoo2/zoo2.dart' as zoo2;

main() {
  print(new Animal());
  print(new zoo2.Animal());
}
```

if you want to import both but only want to use `Animal` from `zoo2` then you can hide one

```
import 'package:zoo1/zoo1.dart' hide Animal;
import 'package:zoo2/zoo2.dart';

main() {
  print(new Animal()); // uses Animal from zoo2 
}
```

I assume for JS they always use some prefix to disambiguate.

Comment: Ah! So they prefix with the name given to the import: class zoo2_zoo2 . Makes sense. Dart is probably the best language ive ever used. It is by far the most cleanest. The best from java, c# and javascript. Do you think google will ever reconsider integrating it into chrome? I guess the js monoculture is unbreakable.

Comment: No, Dart VM in the browser won't happen, but Dart-to-JS will continually be improved. JS in the browser will become better in optimizing x-to-JS code. ES6 features like classes, Promise, ..., improve that already and can be used when they are available in all browsers. IMHO most see it as an advantage, because Dart VM in the browser would make it very tedious to further evolve the language.

Comment: Dart is doing quite well already. Broader adoption just takes time. It's not like there are no other options like as it is for Swift. Flutter will bring a huge boost though. I hope they will eventually give server side support some more love. The community is growing stronger which makes us less depending on the Google Dart team to get stuff done.

Comment: For general discussion you might join https://gitter.im/dart-lang/TALK-general or one of the other Dart rooms

Comment: Thanks for the advice